# How to add a menuItem to a context menu which has a set ItemsSource and ItemContainerStyle in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, contextmenu

I have the following XAML code. The contents in the ItemsSource are displayed as MenuItems.

```
<controls:DropDownButton x:Name="btnOwner"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                 Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Visibility="{Binding IsOwnerVisible}">
<controls:DropDownButton.Content>
    <ContentControl Width="22"
                Height="22"
                Style="{StaticResource iconOwner}"/>
</controls:DropDownButton.Content>
<controls:DropDownButton.DropDown>
    <ContextMenu HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Owners, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource OwnerStyle}">
    </ContextMenu>
</controls:DropDownButton.DropDown>
```

How can I add a new menuItem something like a SubMenuHeader via XAML to this List?

Answer (score 0):

It will create itself. All that you need to provide the `ItemTemplate` in which you will decide what to show and how to show in each `MenuItem`. Otherwise, the default implemention will call `ToString()` method for each item in `Owners`, and will display it in `MenuItem`.

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Owners}">
  <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

Here, I assumed that the type of owner has a property name `Title`. For example, if `Owners` is `ObservableCollection<Owner>`, then `Owner` is defined as:

```
public class Owner
{
     public string Title { get; set;}
     //...
}
```

That is basic idea as to how to use `ItemTemplate`. Now if you want submenuitem in the context menu, then you've to use [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) instead of `DataTemplate` in the `ItemTemplate` definition.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear on what I wanted. So when I click on the drop down button, the context menu show and loads the items from the Owners. I don't have a problem with this. But now I want to add a seperator and another Menu Item that mentions Clear below these Items